# force a script to run at the beginning of a makefile, and display its output

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a script which generates a `version.h` file with various details about the particular build

The script runs various commands, such as:

```
readonly VERSION=$(git describe --always --dirty --long --tags)
readonly NUM_COMMITS=$(git rev-list HEAD | wc -l | bc)
readonly BRANCH=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)
readonly AHEAD_BY=$(git log --oneline origin/${BRANCH}..${BRANCH} | wc -l | bc)
readonly NUM_UNTRACKED=$(git ls-files --exclude-standard --others --full-name -- . | wc -l | bc)
readonly HOSTNAME=$(hostname)
```

It then writes a temporary file, checks against the pre-existing generated file, and if they are different, overwrites the old `version.h` with the new one.

```
#pragma once

/*
 * Version information
 *
 * - This is a generated file - do not edit
 */

namespace foo { namespace app {

static const char VERSION[]       = "26b75cd";
static const char NUM_COMMITS[]   = "224";
static const char BRANCH[]        = "master";
static const char AHEAD_BY[]      = "0";
static const char NUM_UNTRACKED[] = "0";
static const char USER[]          = "steve";
static const char HOSTNAME[]      = "steve-linux";
static const char BUILD_VARIANT[] = "debug";
static const char BUILD_DATE[]    = __DATE__ " "  __TIME__;

}}
```

It also prints to stdout when the file is updated

```
version updated: 26b75cd
```

The version script should be the first thing that is run, and should be run every time the makefile is invoked.

Currently I achieve this by using a *simply expanded variable* in the makefile

```
new_ver := $(shell ./app/gen_version.sh $(BUILD))
```

It works, but any output from the script is captured in `new_var`, and I am unable to display that output.

It's an acceptable trade-off (not displaying the new version), but in an ideal world I would like to display the script output.

I'm unsure as to whether a `.PHONY` target added to the default `all` target will work, because every app has its own target so you can build just that.

```
define do-make-bin
    binaries += $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$1)
    bin_sources += $2

    # a target so users can call 'make <bin-name>' and build only the bin and its dependencies
    $1: $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$1)

    # the target to build the actual binary
    $(addprefix $(BIN_DIR),$1): $(call src_to_obj,$2) $(addsuffix .so,$(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)lib,$3)) $(addsuffix .a,$(addprefix $(LIB_DIR)lib,$4))
    @$(CXX) $(call src_to_obj,$2) -L/usr/lib -L$(SDK_LIB_DIR) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(TARGET_LINK_FLAGS) -Wl$(,)-Bstatic $(addprefix -l,$4) $(addprefix -l,$6) -Wl$(,)-Bdynamic -Wl$(,)-rpath$(,)$(RPATH) $(linkpath) -L$(LIB_DIR) $(sdk_libs) $(tcmalloc_libs) -lpthread -lrt $(addprefix -l,$3) $(addprefix -l,$5) -rdynamic -o $$@
endef
```

calling `make foo` should still check whether `version.h` needs to be updated

Comment: That's the simplest way.  I'm not sure what you mean when you say "more elegant".

Comment: @MadScientist sorry, I've edited the question. Given your response I realise the problem I'm trying to overcome is I am unable to `echo $(new_ver)`  after it's been assigned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to ensure it runs before every target, if you restrict yourself to normal makefile methods, is to put the content in a recipe and then make the target that builds that content be a prerequisite of *every target* in your makefile.  While this *can* be done in such a way that it doesn't cause everything to rebuild every time, it's gross.  Plus, it won't let you put the output into a variable like `new_ver` (you say you want to display that but you don't say whether you need it in the variable as well).

However, if the only problem is that you aren't displaying the value of `new_ver`, *that's* trivially solved:

```
new_ver := $(shell ./app/gen_version.sh $(BUILD))
$(info $(new_ver))
```

Comment: Thanks - so simple, I feel quite lame right now! :)

Comment: is there a way to only call `$(info ...)` if `$(new_ver)` is non-empty?

Comment: never mind - used `ifdef new_ver` which works perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

When a target has no prerequisites and exists as file nothing happens. What you need is to make a conditional prerequisite when temporary file is created. You can use `wildcard` function of gnu/make.

If temporary file is called `version.new.h` and supposing that the script does the check of differences between `version.h` and `version.new.h`. If they are the same it deletes it. Then you can use something like:

```
version.h : $(wildcard version.new.h)
       mv -f version.new.h version.h
```

In order to verify that version.h is created first you should split the jobs.
Then you secure that first job runs first. A sample of the `Makefile` code is:

```
all: version_h other_staff

.PHONY: version_h
version_h:
    ./app/gen_version.sh $(BUILD)
    $(MAKE) version.h

version.h : $(wildcard version.new.h)
    mv -f version.new.h version.h

other_staff: $(EXE) $(LIBS)
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Adding `version_h` to `all` only works if the target we're building is `all`. How do I get it to run no matter what the target is?

Comment: @SteveLorimer if `all` is the first target it will work by default. As mentioned by @MadScientist the most obvious response is to declare it as `prerequisite` to every target. I thought that you already knew it and you did not wanted to do this due it its overhead. So I suggested the workaround above. Anyway, I will edit the response for completeness